# Sql Group by Value1 having count(*) > 1 but with different value 2

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Given an SQL table like this

```
id   value1 value2
---------------
1     1    1
2     1    1
3     1    1
4     2    1
5     2    2
6     3    1
```

I want to find all the value1's  that have duplicate value1 (i.e using group by having count(*)>1) but only if they have different values for value2

So in this example I just want to return **2**

Im using Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
select value1
from t
group by value1
having min(value2) <> max(value2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**use**

```
select * from ( select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value1  ORDER BY Value1 , Value2 ASC) AS RowValue1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value1 , Value2 ORDER BY Value1 , Value2 ASC) AS RowValue2 from Table_1 ) As TableTmp where TableTmp.RowValue1 <> TableTmp.RowValue2
```

**Or**

```
select * from Table_1 where value1 in (select value1 from Table_1 group by value1 having min(value2) <> max(value2) )
```